# How to properly extend generic return type of array

Tags: typescript

I have a database transaction function that can make multiple queries and return result in format [resultQuery1, resultQuery2 and so on for each query]. I'm not sure how can i supply a expected return type to this generic function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggrsAFgewE5QLxQM7FQSwDsBzAWAChRIoAhZZAa0ygG8p8ATALikLgFsARhHQBfClWgAFZNmz5BAGwgxUqAIYgAShGxhkhbBADyAMwAq4XcwDa8JGgA0tegwC6FT%20XXYQhAMZQpnABwPgGsL4BAGIAcgAUAJSsFFBQAPTpUObs2FDqigDumnnqhPlqmlDIplAQAB6Q-sAQHFCounCKwHlQqVD%20BrhQeGXY6s3h5Vg%20foEAPDkNLYQcpYQgNm7MZZtuAHxJPFKoyPz4RvN8iopQAD7Z%205hPLP3tEMBwqOU2AOS4qF%20zhYnB4AEZRB5yGlxOR%20oNDMB3nksPMZHIFMpVBptLp9IYTBYrNh9upivgkaNDBMwgYkhRREA).

Example:

```
type Author = string
type Book = { id: number }
type PossibleArrayResponseOfTypes = [Author, Book] // or [Author, Book, and more]


async function AsyncFN() {
  // T is always an array of expected results  
  const transaction = async <T extends any[] = any[]>(): Promise<null | T> => {
   return ['str', {id: 1}]
  }

  const res = <PossibleArrayResponseOfTypes>await transaction()
}
```

Error:

> Type '(string | { id: number; })[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>     '(string | { id: number; })[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.

Comment: hm, i think i can just cast return as any for now :/

Comment: Yes, it seems to work with a cast... But, why aren't using an Observable for this task?

Comment: @Yennefer i don't like rxjs and angular

Comment: ['str', {id: 1}] is very specific type not generic. Your function has polymorphic type but monomorphic body

Comment: @MaciejSikora return type is just example, it's can be anything.

Comment: In your implementation only `return ['str', {id: 1}]` is a problem. There is no type issue. Can you maybe rephrase what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify any of those types; just let type inference do its thing:

```
async function AsyncFN() {
  // T is always an array of expected results  
  const transaction = async() => {
   return ['str', {id: 1}]
  }

  const res = await transaction()
}
```

With `--noImplicityAny` and `--strictNullChecks` this is just as type-safe as the verbose version.

In general, you should rarely need casts, and the use of casts should be a big red flag. TypeScript's type system is very powerful, and it's almost always possible to express types statically in a way that correctly represents what happens at runtime.

---

Here's what the error message is trying to tell you. The anonymous `async` function is generic, with a type argument `T` that must be a subtype of `any[]`, and it returns a value of this type `T`. The function must, under all circumstances, honour this contract. Let's simplify it a bit without losing the essence:

```
function myFunc<T extends any[]>(): T {
  return ['str']
}
```

Someone could call this function as:

```
myFunc<number[]>()
```

which must return an object of type `number[]`. But the body of the function doesn't do that; it only ever returns a `string[]`.

Comment: but res this way will be any.. That's not a typescript way

Comment: The point is not how the function is _actually_ called. The point is how it _could_ be called, and someone _could_ call it like this with an explicit type argument. That's why the compiler forbids returning something that might break the function's contract. If you want it to be allowed, just write `function myFunc(): any[]`, but then the caller doesn't know what type will be returned.

Comment: i hope there is a way to force supply array type and make it work.

Comment: Why not just declare the return type as `PossibleArrayResponseOfTypes` then? That's the only thing the function ever returns. No need for any generics.

Comment: Exactly how @Thomas says, you put generics, and functions is very specific to one and only type.

Comment: Return array have exact number of ordered items with different types. I should made a better example, sorry :(